# Printing cell elements to text file

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io, cell-array

So I have a cell array containing 5 elements. Each element is a *n by 6* matrix that looks something like this:

```
31399.5 24581.8 24083.9 22764.7 22458   15473.5
81169.4 83739.2 82516.1 84139.6 83552.3 55342.7
41356.6 38413.3 37613   34329.8 38681.8 23949.9
```

For each element in the array, I want to print the corresponding matrix to a text file in the exact same format as above - separating each element of the cell array by a blank line.

Right now I am able to write each element of the cell array to a text file. However, the program doesn't write each row on a new line, it looks more like this:

```
31399.5 24581.8 24083.9 22764.7 22458 15473.5 81169.4 83739.2 82516.1   84139.6 83552.3 55342.7 41356.6 38413.3 37613 34329.8 38681.8 23949.9
```

It writes each matrix as a single line. This is my code (`labels` is the *1 by 5* cell array):

```
fid = fopen('labels.txt','wt');
for i = 1:length(labels)
    fprintf(fid,'%g\t',labels{i}');
    fprintf(fid,'\n');
end
fclose(fid)
```

How can I modify this so that the data is presented row by row? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fprintf` to print out matrices is never very friendly.  Try using [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) instead of `fprintf` and in the case where you want to append the results to file, use the `-append` flag.  You'll also want to adjust the precision since `dlmwrite` by default rounds numbers.  Something like this could work:

```
for i = 1:length(labels)
    dlmwrite('labels.txt', sprintf('Label %d', i), '-append');
    dlmwrite('labels.txt', labels{i}, '-append', 'precision', 6);
    dlmwrite('labels.txt', ' ', '-append');
end
```

Take note that I had to do a bit of a hack to perform a carriage return before you write the next matrix for appending.  Simply put, I appended a space after the matrix to force a new line when appending.  For each carriage return, you're going to see a blank line with one space but I'm assuming this won't be a problem.  I've also taken the liberty in adding in `Label i` before each matrix where `i` is the matrix seen at cell `i`.

Comment: Great, much easier to work with than fprintf. This does exactly what I want, thank you.

Comment: @eyesenberg my pleasure.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayreng Hey, I have been struggling to simply write "Label i" on top of each matrix in the text file to separate them(where i is the i'th index in the cell array). I've been using fprintf(...) to write the header but have been getting strange results. Would you be able to adjust the code provided so that it does this? I'm not sure why I'm finding this difficult. Again, grateful for any help :)

Comment: I sure can. Give me a little while. I'm not at a computer currently.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!